# photonView and Photon Network

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I have a little problem with connection by PhotonNetwork. I want to show me a list of players by press L. Everything is okey but when i run the game and press L, Unity shows me that no one has joined. Help me please. It also wrtie PhotonView with ID 1 has no method "GraczWszedł" marked with the PunRPC or @PunRPC(JS) property! Args: PhotonPlayer
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;
using Debug = UnityEngine.Debug;
using Photon.Realtime;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MenadzerPolaczen : Photon.MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start(){

    }

    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
            Gracz.DebugListyGraczy();
    }

    public void Polacz() {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings("Dunkierka_1.0");
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 20),  PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString());
    }

    void OnJoinedLobby(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }

    void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed(){
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(null);
    }

    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level) {
        if (level != 0)
            PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    }

    void OnPhotonPlayerConnected(PhotonPlayer pp) {

    }

    void OnPhotonPlayerDisconnected(PhotonPlayer pp) {

    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void GraczWszedl(PhotonPlayer pp){
        Gracz gracz = new Gracz();        
        gracz.nick = pp.NickName;
        gracz.pp = pp;
        Gracz.gracze.Add(gracz);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void GraczWyszedl(PhotonPlayer pp) {

    }

    void OnCreatedRoom(){
        photonView.RPC(("GraczWszedł"), PhotonTargets.AllBuffered, PhotonNetwork.player);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the number of players in the room that your player is in:

1. Make Sure to Create a room.
2. Make Sure to Join a room.
3. PhotonNetwork.playerList retrieves list of all players that are in the current room of local players along with that player itself. 
   https://documentation.help/Photon-v1.81/class_photon_network.html#a2dc5e6cba79f899d9952f804db35b2f3
4. Also You can list all players properties by setting PhotonPlayer.customProperties
   https://documentation.help/Photon-v1.81/class_photon_player.html#af8815abb8edaafbe6bddbf328f9612fb